# Rendering non-latin fonts (with Anti-Grain Geometry Library)

Tags: c++, graphics, fonts, rendering, non-english

I want to render shapes and text with different properties (pen width, color, etc.) in a platform independent C++ application. I do not want to rely on platform specifics (like OpenGL or font libraries) and found that the Anti-Grain-Geometry library (http://www.antigrain.com/) seems to be fine.

Rendering of plain English characters looks simple using the freefont which ships with the library. But how does rendering of non-English (e.g. "ä", "ü", "?", etc.) and non-Latin characters (e.g. Chinese or Russian) work?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration of the Freetype library is easy and works fine with foreign characters (at least those which I tested).

Comment: You can use Anti Grain Geometry , it's fast and easy to learn. I have unfortunatly the sad news to tell you the author Maxim Shemanarev died last year. RIP Max.